# What is the difference between "during a day" and "during the day"?

Tags: articles, time-words

What is the difference?

I eat a lot during a day.

I eat a lot during the day.

Comment: I simply "adore" those who contribute to questions by voting to close them. Keep up to your excellent job!

Comment: This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please [edit] to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context. See: [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Comment: @user1425: I didn't vote, but, frustrated passive-aggressive sarcasm aside, close-voting actually *is* important to the health of the site, and to questions in particular. The point of closing questions is to prevent collecting a lot of bad answers that can easily be prompted by various types of bad questions. Now, if the asker was the only one being helped by the answers, it might be OK to let them suffer bad answers for bad questions. But since our goal is to have good answers for future readers, that's not fair or helpful to them, so we moderate the site to avoid that kind of problem. (1/2)

Comment: @user1425: Often, question closing is the key motivator that gets someone to edit a question to fix problems with it, since it's a lot harder to ignore than a comment someone left. Without closure, we would have less effort being put into asking questions, and less effort put into *editing* them as well, because question quality wouldn't actually matter much.

Comment: Actually the question is brilliant. Any learner would agree. It's simple but precious. No other additional research is needed. Those who voted are natives who don't understand the way a learner sees things.

Comment: @user1425: With this level of detail, we have to guess to figure out what you do or don't know, what area we should be addressing, what context you think this will apply to. You have a higher chance of getting answers that miss the point, or that just tell you what you already know, or that don't go into enough detail. If we know what you've done to figure it out, more specifically where your confusion or uncertainty lies, we can give a much more useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first, ***during a day***, means "over the course of a 24 hour period", or possibly "between waking and sleeping". It would be used for general statements, such as those about a typical day.

The second, ***during the day***, has two possible meanings. Either it is referring to a *specific* day, or it means "during the *daytime*". That is, not in the evening or at night. If it means *daytime*, then it might be general, or it might be regarding a specific day.

Answer (score 1):

> During a day

means that something happened encompassing the entire 24-hour period of one day.

Example: "I sleep for eight hours during a day."

Please note that here in the western U.S., this phrase is uncommon.  It would be more common to hear "each day" or "daily."

> During the day

means that something happened within or at some time during the 24-hour period of the currently referenced day.  It may also mean that something happened during daylight hours.

Example: "I sleep sometime during the day." (Referencing some 24-hour period.)

Example: "I work night shift, so I sleep during the day." (Referencing the 12ish-hour period of daylight.)

Answer (score 1):

> I eat a lot during a day
>   I eat three meals during a day.

This means during a typical or generalized day.

"I eat a lot during the day" could have the exact same meaning. Ot it could mean during the daylight, as opposed to "during the night" context, which is not provided in the question, would often make this clear. It might refer to a specific or recent day, but probably not, and not without context indicating this.

> During the day, be sure to eat well.
>
> Get the question answered during the day.

Here a specific day is intended Context might indicate a particular day, failing that it would normally mean the current day.

Answer (score 0):

In the usage of the terms above, the difference is that in the latter or second example, it indicates that it happened in a specific somewhat nearer day to when it is spoken. The first example seems to indicate it happened at some non-specific day . It is like some day.